# convert string to decimal ("3942.000000000000")

Tags: c#, decimal, converters

Hi I can't find any good way to format this string to a decimal.

`3942.000000000000`

Any ideas on it?

**EDIT**
How is this now a valid question? Some (as I) might miss the `CultureInfo` that's suppose to go in the `decimal.Parse`, for just different culture formats.

Also I didn't want a `float`, so making a `float` to `decimal` is extra steps.
Just my two cents

Comment: Do you mean *parse*? Formatting converts from a value to a string, not the other way round. Look at `decimal.Parse`.

Comment: How should the output differ from the decimal conversion of `3942`? Or, how does the standard approach fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to float number C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365566/parse-string-to-float-number-c-sharp)

Comment: Must be missing something. Seems to simple to be true.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist tried it?

Comment: @JanDvorak well the number can be 3333.23459876545, `decimal.parse` can't handle that. Except when doing the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: It's still a valid question. Missing the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`and it wont work.

Comment: @Dejan.S - Actually, I was meaning that I fear you have some other problem that prevents you from using decimal.Parse as Jon correctly suggested - that would be the first thing that comes up on a google search, and it seemed strange you missed that (2k user, 5 gold, pretty trustworthy I would say). Sorry to have seemed enigmatic, what I meant was "Do you have something that prevents using standard .Parse methods?"

Comment: Now I see that it was just a problem related to the decimal separator. Didn't realize you may just be missing that step (living in a country where the decimal separator is "," and working daily with code that uses ".", I tend to give culture conversions as given. Again, sorry for the confusion ^_^).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `Decimal.Parse` with specifying decimal separator?

```
var yourString = "3942.000000000000";
var info = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
var parsed = Decimal.Parse(yourString, info);
```

EDIT:
as Jon suggested you can use InvariantCulture:

```
var yourString = "3942.000000000000";
var parsed = Decimal.Parse(yourString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It would be cleaner just to specify the invariant culture, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for suggestion, I changed my answer to include that

Comment: @wudzik Thanks for this. Went with Jons example. Didn't know about the NumberFormatInfo, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

Any reason you cannot use

```
Convert.ToDecimal("3942.000000000000");
```

Comment: Can you post your code. So that it will be easy to see what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParse` on the `string`.  Please note the `out` in the call.

```
string yourString = "3942.0000000000"
decimal yourDecimal;
decimal.TryParse(yourString, out yourDecimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryParse:

```
string yourString = "3942.0000000000"

decimal d;
if (decimal.TryParse(yourString, out d))
{
     //OK
}
else
{
     // Handle failure
}
```

Comment: Was the absence of a closing parenthesis intentional or accidental? :)

Comment: I only did it in my head. Didn't want to go in and edit your answer just in case it was actually intentional.